# Combine If statement with Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to **combine a vlookup formula with an If condition**. To be more exact, I have a worksheet where I want a vlookup formula to be executed in the cell of the column G if the cell of the column E **AND** F is 0. Just to be clear, the variable *lastrow3* and *ws1* are WELL defined and have proper values. Also, I have run the code without the if condition (just the vlookup) and it runs just fine. So there is no chance that there is an issue with these variables. Moreover, I want the ***vlookup to be dynamic***. I have written 4 different types of code. I am providing them below.

**CODE1**

```
For i = 2 To lastrow3
ws1.Range("G" & i).Formula = "=IF(E" & i & "+ F" & i & " = 0, " & Chr(34) & "VLOOKUP(C"&i&",'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:I,4,FALSE)" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "No" & Chr(34) & ")"
Next i
```

This code gives me an error in this part: `"VLOOKUP(C"&i&",`saying that there is a syntax error.

**CODE2**

```
For Each cell In ws1.Range("G2:G" & lastrow3)
    If cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = 0 Then
        If cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = 0 Then
        cell.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:I,4,FALSE),"""")"
        End If
    End If
Next cell
```

This code gives an error in this part: `If cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = 0 Then` saying that there is type mismatch. Also, this code does not have dynamic vlookup, so it vlookups only for cell C2.

**CODE3**

```
With ws1
   For i = 2 To lastrow3
       If .Cells(i, "E").Value2 = 0 And .Cells(i, "F").Value2 = 0 Then
       .Cells(i, "G").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C$" & i&",'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:I,4,FALSE),"""")"
       End If
   Next cell
End With
```

This code gives me an error in this part : `.Cells(i, "G").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C$" & i&",'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:I,4,FALSE),"""")"` saying the there is a syntax error.

**CODE4**

```
With ws1
    .Range("G2:G" & lastrow3).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:I,4,FALSE),"""")"
    .Range("G2:G" & lastrow3).Value = .Range("G2:G" & lastrow3).Value
End With
```

This code runs fine (this is the code I ran and verified that the variables are well defined) bit does not include the If condition. 
I want to declare that this code runs really fast (with the With ws1 and End With) so if it is possible to make this code ran by adding the if condition then it would be perfect.

**CODE5 (-> my attempt at adding If condition in CODE4)**

```
With ws1
If  .Range("G2:G" & lastrow3).Offset(0, -1).Value = 0 And .Range("G2:G" & lastrow3).Offset(0, -2).Value = 0 Then
    .Range("G2:G" & lastrow3).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:I,4,FALSE),"""")"
End If
    .Range("G2:G" & lastrow3).Value = .Range("G2:G" & lastrow3).Value
End With
```

This code gives me an error in this part : `If .Range("G2:G" & lastrow3).Offset(0, -1).Value = 0 And .Range("G2:G" & lastrow3).Offset(0, -2).Value = 0 Then` saying that there is an type mismatch.

***SUMMARY***

I am trying to combine speed and accuracy in the code. The code with the With and End With, from what I have searched, is the fastest. However, If I manage to solve it with another code then no issue. The main errors I get is in the vlookup formula, when I try to make it dynamic and in the if condition, when I try to find whether the offsets have 0 values.

I am adding the entire code so far (although I think it is not important)

***ENTIRE CODE***

```
Sub Pharma_Stock_Report()



Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
StartTime = Timer



Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim lastrow1 As Long
Dim lastrow2 As Long
Dim lastrow3 As Long
Dim CopyRange As Range
Dim i As Long

spath1 = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Pharma replenishment.xlsm"
spath2 = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\NOT OK.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open spath1
Workbooks.Open spath2

Set ws1 = Workbooks("Pharma Stock Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Pharma Stock Report")
Set ws2 = Workbooks("Pharma replenishment.xlsm").Worksheets("Replenishment")
Set ws3 = Workbooks("NOT OK.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ws1
    .Cells.Clear
End With

With ws2
lastrow1 = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 4 To lastrow1
        If .Cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Or .Cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
            If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                Set CopyRange = .Range("A" & i & ":F" & i)
            Else
                Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, .Range("A" & i & ":F" & i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

CopyRange.Copy
With ws1.Range("A2")
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With

ws2.Range("A4:F4").Copy
With ws1.Range("A1")
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Workbooks("Pharma replenishment.xlsm").Close

ws3.Range("I1").Copy
With ws1.Range("G1")
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With

lastrow3 = ws1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With ws1
    .Range("G2:G" & lastrow3).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:I,4,FALSE),"""")"
    .Range("G2:G" & lastrow3).Value = .Range("G2:G" & lastrow3).Value
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Workbooks("NOT OK.xlsx").Close

With ws1.Range("A1:G" & lastrow3)
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Font.Color = vbBlack
    .Font.Name = "Calibri"
    .Font.Italic = False
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlDouble
    .Borders.Weight = xlThin
    .Borders.Color = vbBlack
End With

With ws1.Range("A1:G1")
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 41
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Size = 14
    .Font.Italic = True
End With

With ws1.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

ws1.Range("A1:G1").AutoFilter
ws1.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ws1.AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True



SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CODE1 has some issues. You've inserted some `Chr(34)` around the `VLOOKUP` and unless you want the cell to display the lookup formula, instead of the *result* of the lookup then they need to go.

```
ws1.Range("G" & i).Formula = "=IF(E" & i & "+ F" & i & " = 0, " & "VLOOKUP(C" & i & ",'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:I,4,FALSE)" & ", " & Chr(34) & "No" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

To blank out zeros and `#N/A` -

```
ws1.Range("G" & i).Formula = "=IFNA(IF(E" & i & "+ F" & i & " = 0, " & "IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C" & i & ",'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:I,4,FALSE),0)=0,"""",IFNA(VLOOKUP(C" & i & ",'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:I,4,FALSE),0))" & ", " & Chr(34) & "No" & Chr(34) & "),"""")"
```

Comment: Ok that solved the issue! You are right! But the issue is that I want the macro to replace wither 0 or N/A with empty cell. In this code, if formula has no match, it prints 0 or N/A. What should I edit

Comment: To blank out the #N/A, wrap it in a `IFNA` formula - e.g. `=IFNA(VLOOKUP-formula,"")`.

Comment: To blank out the zeros, use `IF` combined with the `IFNA` - `=IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP-formula,0)=0,"",IFNA(VLOOKUP-formula,0))`

Comment: I am getting a type mismatch... I guess I did it all wrong because we combine the if condition in the beginning

Comment: I've added to my answer to cover these scenarios off.

Comment: CLR now, instead of showing the result of the formula, where it should be, it shows 7 and also, the NA have not gone...

Comment: Try it now, I'd made it work on my machine and forgot to put it back.

Comment: now the vlookup works great! the only thing left is the NA.. thats the only remaning issue

Comment: The only reason you should be getting `#N/A` now would be if the part outside the `IFNA` is hitting an issue or the actual result of the VLOOKUP is seeing the text value of "#N/A"  - i.e. you've copy/pasted over an error. Can you check?

Comment: yes I just checked it! the N/A is the value of one of the two offsets in the if condition. can we bypass that?

Comment: Answer altered. I've wrapped the whole lot in an `IFNA` making some of the internal ones redundant. But it works. I'd suggest raising a new question if you need further help with this as you've moved far outside the bounds of your original question. Good luck!

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks a lot CLR! that is fantastic

Answer (score 1):

The first code is an easy fix: there actually is a syntax error, as vba requires spaces between variable names and the `&`-Operator. Adding spaces like

```
ws1.Range("G" & i).Formula = "=IF(E" & i & "+ F" & i & " = 0, " & Chr(34) & "VLOOKUP(C" & i & ",'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:I,4,FALSE)" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "No" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

will solve that problem.

Comment: It did solve the error message box, but instead of showing the result of the vlookup, it prints the formula instead. Also, when there is no result for the formula, can we have the macro replace the No by empty cell?

Comment: With me it works and inserts the formula. You can check for `IsError(cell)` and clear the cell if it returns true.

Comment: Oops copy-pasted the wrong line... wouldnt work with those `chr(34)`...

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is testing a range of values which is likely why you are getting type issues

Instead it would be easier to add the if test in the formula (Then using R1C1 notation to create referenced lookups)

```
.Range("G2:G" & lastrow3).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(RC[-2]=0,RC[-1]=0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-4],'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!C[-1]:C[2],4,FALSE),""""),"Null Values")"
```